# How to put items into priority queues?

Tags: python, queue

In the Python docs,

> The lowest valued entries are retrieved first (the lowest valued entry is the one returned by `sorted(list(entries))[0]`). A typical pattern for entries is a tuple in the form: `(priority_number, data)`.

It appears the queue will be sorted by priority then data, which may not be always correct. Suppose data "item 2", is enqueued before "item 1", item 1 will still go first. In another docs page, [heapq](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/heapq.html?highlight=heapq#priority-queue-implementation-notes), it suggests the use of a counter. So I will store my data like `entry = [priority, count, task]`. Isn't there something like

```
PriorityQueue.put(item, priority)
```

Then I won't need to implement the ordering myself?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As far as I know, what you're looking for isn't available out of the box. Anyway, note that it wouldn't be hard to implement:

```
from Queue import PriorityQueue

class MyPriorityQueue(PriorityQueue):
    def __init__(self):
        PriorityQueue.__init__(self)
        self.counter = 0

    def put(self, item, priority):
        PriorityQueue.put(self, (priority, self.counter, item))
        self.counter += 1

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _, _, item = PriorityQueue.get(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return item


queue = MyPriorityQueue()
queue.put('item2', 1)
queue.put('item1', 1)

print queue.get()
print queue.get()
```

Example output:

```
item2
item1
```

Comment: I am new to Python, to me, `PriorityQueue.__init__(self)` appears to be calling a static method. Is there something like `parent.__init__(self)`?

Comment: Oh, or should I interpret it as: I am calling the static method passing in `self`. If I call the object method, I won't need that?

Comment: `PriorityQueue.__init__(self)` is more properly written `super(MyPriorityQueue, self).__init__()`, but it is valid.

Comment: @larsmans I tried that, but it seems that `PriorityQueue` is an old style class and it doesn't work with `super`.

Comment: It appears you're right. Rather surprising; please excuse my previous comment.

Comment: In python 3.6, `super().__init__()` works with PriorityQueue.

Answer (score 36):

Just use the second item of the tuple as a secondary priority if a alphanumeric sort on your string data isn't appropriate.  A date/time priority would give you a priority queue that falls back to a FIFIO queue when you have multiple items with the same priority.  Here's some example code with just a secondary numeric priority.  Using a datetime value in the second position is a pretty trivial change, but feel free to poke me in comments if you're not able to get it working.

### Code

```
import Queue as queue

prio_queue = queue.PriorityQueue()
prio_queue.put((2, 8, 'super blah'))
prio_queue.put((1, 4, 'Some thing'))
prio_queue.put((1, 3, 'This thing would come after Some Thing if we sorted by this text entry'))
prio_queue.put((5, 1, 'blah'))

while not prio_queue.empty():
    item = prio_queue.get()
    print('%s.%s - %s' % item)
```

### Output

```
1.3 - This thing would come after Some Thing if we didn't add a secondary priority
1.4 - Some thing
2.8 - super blah
5.1 - blah
```

### Edit

Here's what it looks like if you use a timestamp to fake FIFO as a secondary priority using a date.  I say fake because it's only approximately FIFO as entries that are added very close in time to one another may not come out exactly FIFO.  I added a short sleep so this simple example works out in a reasonable way.  Hopefully this helps as another example of how you might get the ordering you're after.

```
import Queue as queue
import time

prio_queue = queue.PriorityQueue()
prio_queue.put((2, time.time(), 'super blah'))
time.sleep(0.1)
prio_queue.put((1, time.time(), 'This thing would come after Some Thing if we sorted by this text entry'))
time.sleep(0.1)
prio_queue.put((1, time.time(), 'Some thing'))
time.sleep(0.1)
prio_queue.put((5, time.time(), 'blah'))

while not prio_queue.empty():
    item = prio_queue.get()
    print('%s.%s - %s' % item)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made something like this to accomplish a FIFO similar to gfortune, but without the need of calling time.time() everywhere: (Python 3 only)

```
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(order=True)
class PrioritizedItem:
    prio: int
    timestamp: float = field(init=False, default_factory=time.time)
    data: object = field(compare=False)
```

Now you can do:

```
import queue

item1 = PrioritizedItem(0, "hello world")
item2 = PrioritizedItem(0, "what ever")
q = queue.PriorityQueue()
q.put(item1)
q.put(item2)
```

And be sure, they will always be extracted in the same order.